# Deriving multivariate equations with respect to one variable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

When deriving a multivariable equation wrt one variable, am I correct in thinking that one takes the derivative of the target variable and leaves the other function variables unchanged? For example, I've been looking at the cost function for logistic regression:

$$L(a,y) = -(y * log(a) + (1 - y) * log(1 - a)) $$

I can now see how to derive equation below, but when computing this derivation I'm only differentiating the $a$ terms (as that's the variable with respect to which I'm computing the derivative of $L$):

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = -\frac{y}{a} + \frac{1-y}{1-a} $$

Am I correct in thinking that when computing $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial a}$ we should leave the $y$ terms unchanged, and should only worry about taking the derivatives of the $a$ terms? My calculus book only deals with single variable derivatives, so I'd be very grateful for any help others can offer on this question!

Comment: Yes this is basically the entire idea behind partial derivatives, unless y specifically depends on a, it is treated like a constant

Comment: Thanks @Triatticus! When would y specifically depend on a?

Comment: If for example $y=y(a)$, that is an implicit dependence on a, but it could be made explicit with a formula. It can also be completely independent from a like your equation is.

Comment: In case others end up here with a similar question, the Khan academy lectures on multivariable calculus are awesome: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrcCbdWwCBc&list=PLSQl0a2vh4HC5feHa6Rc5c0wbRTx56nF7&index=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that we `leave the other function variables unchanged` is not accurate. When taking a partial derivative with respect to one of the variables (of a multivariate functions), *we treat the remaining variables as **constants***. And that's not the same as "leaving them unchanged". For example, if
$$L(a,y)=y\ln(a)+y,$$
then
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}=y\cdot\frac{1}{a}+0=\frac{y}{a}.$$
Note that we didn't leave the second $y$ unchanged: with respect to $a$, it's a constant term whose derivative is zero.

(P.S. By the way, you're using the term `term` incorrectly.)

Comment: Thanks @zipirovich, that's helpful. To make sure I understand, if the second y were y^3, it would still evaluate to + 0 in the dL/da line, right? Also, do you happen to know of a dependable and non-mathematician-friendly reference for the definition of mathematical terms? There are a few I'd like to look up, but sources I've found are too vague or too technical...

Comment: @duhaime: Yes, that's correct! As for a glossary of math terms, to be honest, I can't think of any at the moment. But if I remember or find something like that, I will come and let you know. Sorry...

Comment: I'm coming back to this after some months. Can you please tell me why my usage of the word `term` is incorrect above? I'd be grateful if you could...

Comment: @duhaime: Roughly speaking, ***terms*** are parts of the expression that are added to or subtracted from each other. For example, the expression $L(a,y)=-y\ln(a)-(1-y)\ln(1-a)$ is the sum of its two terms: $\color{blue}{-y\ln(a)}$ and $\color{blue}{-(1-y)\ln(1-a)}$. There's no "$y$ term" in here, not in the sense that you were using the word, because there's no "$\ldots+y+\ldots$" in this expression.

Comment: Ah, excellent, thank you very much. Yes, I had meant to refer to those terms that include a/y and have some coefficients, but it seems that's not common parlance--it seems instead that a "y-term" can only refer to a y value separated by +/-. It seems strange, as that term itself has a coefficient (1), but so be it...

Comment: @duhaime: In fact, what you're referring to **is** a common parlance. Say, let's look at an expression like $3x^2+5x-7$. It's very common to refer to the $x^2$-term or the $x$-term (as well as the constant term) in this expression, where the $x^2$-term is "$3x^2$" and the $x$-term is "$5x$" (and the constant term is "$-7$"). But there's a subtle distinction between saying "the $x$-term" as a descriptor or saying that $x$ is a term -- where the latter would literally mean having "$\ldots+x+\ldots$". It seemed to me that you were a little bit confused there, which is why I made that remark.

Comment: ah perfect, that makes sense. Thanks again for following up.